# Remove button in gridview

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a gridview with 8 buttons, 2 rows and 4 columns.  I am trying to delete a button or even a row..a row might be better..I want this deletion to take place when I click on a button..any button.  I am having trouble with this.  I will show you code so far:

Mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView text;
private GridView gridView;
private TextView timerValue;
private Boolean firstclick = false;
private long startTime = 0L;
private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
private Button buttonclicked;
Random r = new Random();
//private int[] rannumbers_array = new int[32];
private int[] shuffle_array = new int[4];
private String[] items = new String[8];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedback);
    timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);
    timerValue.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int ranval = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if ( (i % 4) == 0)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
            {
                shuffle_array[x] = 0;
            }
            do {
                ranval = r.nextInt(100);
            } while((ranval % 2) != 0);
        }
        else
        {
            do {
                ranval = r.nextInt(100);
            } while((ranval % 2) == 0); 
        }
        shuffle_array[j] = ranval;
        j++;
        if(j >= 4)
        {
            j = 0;
            shuffle(shuffle_array);
            do {
               items[k] = Integer.toString(shuffle_array[j]);
               k++;
               j++;
            } while(k <= i);
            j = 0;
        }
        //rannumbers_array[i] = r.nextInt(100);
        //items[i] = Integer.toString(rannumbers_array[i]);
    }
    k = 0;




    gridView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.myGridView);
    final CustomGridAdapter gridAdapter = new CustomGridAdapter(MainActivity.this, items);
    gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
    buttonclicked = gridAdapter.getbutton();
    gridView.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            gridView.setSelection(gridView.getCount() - 1);
        }
    });
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(!firstclick)
            {
               customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
               firstclick = true;
            }
            buttonclicked.setVisibility(view.GONE);
```

my CustomGridAdapter:

```
public class CustomGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private String[] items;
private Button button;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomGridAdapter(Context context, String[] items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, null);
    }
    button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item);
    button.setHeight(175);
    button.setText(items[position]);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public Button getbutton()
{
    return button;
}
```

}

cell.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/grid_item"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:maxHeight="175dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:text="05"
android:textSize="25sp"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"/>
```

activitymain.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timerValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:text="@string/timerVal"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/myGridView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/feedback"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

The buttonclicked.setVisibility(view.GONE); did not work, gave me an error I think.  I am trying to have a button or item be clicked and have that item and/or the row the item is in to be deleted..how can I do this?  What am I missing?  After the deletion occurs I will need to redraw the grid to have less items in it too.  Those are the two things that I am stumped on now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the view parameter on the OnItemClick implementation, this function give to you the position of the grid, the cell view and the id of the custom item on your adapter.

```
   gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(!firstclick)
        {
           customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
           firstclick = true;
        }
        //buttonclicked.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        view.findViewById(R.id.grid_item).setVisibility(view.GONE);
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the location of the declared input to OnCreate with final.